# Subtract each row of matrix A from every row of matrix B without loops

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, array-broadcasting

Given two arrays, `A` (shape: M X C) and `B` (shape: N X C), is there a way to subtract each row of `A` from each row of `B` without using loops? The final output would be of shape (M N X C).

---

#### Example

```
A = np.array([[  1,   2,   3], 
              [100, 200, 300]])

B = np.array([[  10,   20,   30],
              [1000, 2000, 3000],
              [ -10,  -20,   -2]])
```

Desired result (can have some other shape) (edited):

```
array([[  -9,   -18,   -27],
       [-999, -1998, -2997],
       [  11,    22,     5],
       [  90,   180,   270],
       [-900, -1800, -2700],
       [ 110,   220,   302]])

Shape: 6 X 3
```

*(Loop is too slow, and "outer" subtracts each element instead of each row)*

Comment: I edited the question to show the desired result

Comment: The given desired output does not match the description of the desired output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to do it efficiently (without using any loops) by leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) like:

```
In [28]: (A[:, np.newaxis] - B).reshape(-1, A.shape[1])
Out[28]: 
array([[   -9,   -18,   -27],
       [ -999, -1998, -2997],
       [   11,    22,     5],
       [   90,   180,   270],
       [ -900, -1800, -2700],
       [  110,   220,   302]])
```

---

Or, for a little faster solution than [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we would have to use [numexpr](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) like:

```
In [31]: A_3D = A[:, np.newaxis]
In [32]: import numexpr as ne

# pass the expression for subtraction as a string to `evaluate` function
In [33]: ne.evaluate('A_3D - B').reshape(-1, A.shape[1])
Out[33]: 
array([[   -9,   -18,   -27],
       [ -999, -1998, -2997],
       [   11,    22,     5],
       [   90,   180,   270],
       [ -900, -1800, -2700],
       [  110,   220,   302]], dtype=int64)
```

---

One more least efficient approach would be by using [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to match the shapes of both arrays. But, note that this is the *least efficient* option because it makes **copies** when trying to match the shapes.

```
In [27]: np.repeat(A, B.shape[0], 0) - np.tile(B, (A.shape[0], 1))
Out[27]: 
array([[   -9,   -18,   -27],
       [ -999, -1998, -2997],
       [   11,    22,     5],
       [   90,   180,   270],
       [ -900, -1800, -2700],
       [  110,   220,   302]])
```

Comment: I'd reverse the order of your suggestions -- broadcasting here is the canonical way.  Manual repeats and tiles should be reserved for when they're needed.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely prefer the broadcasting method.

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with numexpr before. Will try that too.

Comment: @kmario23 this create problem for large matrices. I have matrix A (180000,3) and matrix B (50000,3) .. all doubles. When I tried to calculate `A[:, np.newaxis] - B` I get MemoryError. Any recommendation to help solve this problem please?   
Looping takes 1100 seconds.

Comment: @MubeenShahid Yes, there might be a problem with such huge array sizes. With the sizes you mentioned, one would need at least 101 GB of RAM (i.e. `(180000* 50000* 3 * 4)/1024/1024/1024`), assuming no other processes are using any RAM at all, which is of course not possible. To circumvent this issue, `numpy.memmap` might help but I haven't done that myself. You can also post a new question for gathering more opinions from others...

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) ([`numpy.kron`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[  1,   2,   3], 
...               [100, 200, 300]])
>>> B = np.array([[  10,   20,   30],
...               [1000, 2000, 3000],
...               [ -10,  -20,   -2]])
>>> (m,c) = A.shape
>>> (n,c) = B.shape
>>> np.kron(A,np.ones((n,1))) - np.kron(np.ones((m,1)),B)
array([[   -9.,   -18.,   -27.],
       [ -999., -1998., -2997.],
       [   11.,    22.,     5.],
       [   90.,   180.,   270.],
       [ -900., -1800., -2700.],
       [  110.,   220.,   302.]])
```