# Confusion regarding np.tile and numpy broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcasting

Suppose I have a 2D `numpy` array `A` of shape `(m, n)`. I would like to create a 3D array `B` of shape `(m, n, k)` such that `B[:, :, l]` is a copy of `A` for any slice `l`. I could think of two ways to do this:

```
np.tile(A, (m, n, k))
```

or

```
np.repeat(A[:, :, np.newaxis], k, axis=-1)
```

The first way seems simpler, but I the docs for `np.tile` mentioned:

```
Note: Although tile may be used for broadcasting, it is strongly
recommended to use numpy's broadcasting operations and functions.
```

Why is this so, and is this an issue with `np.repeat` as well?

My other worry is that if `m == n == k`, then would `np.tile()` create confusion regarding which axis is augmented?

In summary, I have two questions:

1. Why is `np.tile` not preferred, and would `m == n == k` cause unexpected behavior in some cases?
2. Which of the two ways above is more efficient in terms of time and memory? Is there a cleaner or more efficient way than both approaches?

Comment: Because you do not "*tile*", you "*broadcast*". Tiling is used to repeat a submatrix several times, like for instance a 2x2 into 4x4. Although you *can* use it to broadcast, it is better to use tools that map directly on the problem, since usually these do it faster, use less memory, etc.

Comment: Your `np.tile` call doesn't do what you're trying to do. `np.tile` doesn't work anything like that; it takes repetition counts, not a new shape, and it's not going to guess from the values of `m`, `n`, and `k` how to align the old shape to the new.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, what should be the correct `np.tile` usage in this case? I thought `np.tile` could prepend new axes as well...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In my case, I actually need to store the new 3D array as well, so I assume it wouldn't be different than `broadcasting`, right?

Comment: `Look at the code for `tile`.  It uses a reshape plus `repeat`.  `repeat` is the compiled function.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the pointer! So the second way should always be equivalent to or more efficient then.

Comment: What do you do with `B` once you've got it? (The answer to that question helps inform the options for building `B` in the first place.)

Comment: With `tile` (or `repeat`) you make a new array with that shape.  With broadcasting you make a `view` that behaves like the larger array, but without taking up more memory.  It's a temporary construct used in other calculations.

Comment: @MarkDickinson In my case, I actually have an array `A1` of shape `(m, n)` and an array `A2` of shape `(n, k)`, and I wanted to expand each to a 3D array of shape `(m, n, k)` and compute the sum array.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right in that the current `np.tile(A, (m, n, k))` does not work... Just curious, what should be the right way to tile in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Hilbert: If the purpose of this expansion is to compute that sum array, then you *don't* need to store a physically expanded array. Broadcasting will be quite sufficient.

Comment: @Hilbert I'd like to point out that `np.tile` and `np.repeat` are inefficient in the sense that it makes *copies* of the array whereas broadcasting doesn't make a copy. I think the docs mention this as a note so that you don't explicitly make copies of arrays when you're doing some processsing like pair-wise row subtraction or something. Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359053/subtract-each-row-of-matrix-a-from-every-row-of-matrix-b-without-loops/48359137#48359137 to understand why **broadcasting is efficient** and preferred over `tile` and `repeat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [100]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

Using repeat to add a new dimension at the end:

```
In [101]: B = np.repeat(A[:,:,np.newaxis], 2, axis=-1)
In [102]: B.shape
Out[102]: (3, 4, 2)
```

Using tile and repeat to add a new dimension at the beginning:

```
In [104]: np.tile(A, (2,1,1)).shape
Out[104]: (2, 3, 4)
In [105]: np.repeat(A[None,:,:], 2, axis=0).shape
Out[105]: (2, 3, 4)
```

If we specify 2 repeats on the last dimension with tile, it gives a different shape

```
In [106]: np.tile(A, (1,1,2)).shape
Out[106]: (1, 3, 8)
```

Note what `tile` says about prepending a dimension with the repeats tuple is larger than the shape.

But if you used the expanded array in a calculation as described in the comments, you don't need to make a full repeated copy.  Temporary views of the right shape can be used instead, taking advantage of `broadcasting`.

```
In [107]: A1=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [108]: A2=np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
In [109]: A3=A1[:,:,None] + A2[None,:,:]
In [110]: A3.shape
Out[110]: (3, 4, 2)
In [111]: A3
Out[111]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 7,  8],
        [10, 11],
        [13, 14]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [11, 12],
        [14, 15],
        [17, 18]]])
```

With the `None` (`np.newaxis`), the array views are (3,4,1) and (1,4,2) shaped, which broadcast together as (3,4,2).  I could leave off the `None` in the 2nd case, since broadcasting will add the automatically.  But the trailing `None` is required.

```
In [112]: (A1[:,:,None] + A2).shape
Out[112]: (3, 4, 2)
```

To add a 1d array (last dimension):

```
In [113]: (A1[:,:,None] + np.array([1,2])[None,None,:]).shape
Out[113]: (3, 4, 2)
In [114]: (A1[:,:,None] + np.array([1,2])).shape
Out[114]: (3, 4, 2)
```

Two basic broadcasting steps:

- add size 1 dimensions as the start as needed (automatic `[None,....]`)
- expand all size 1 dimensions to the shared size

This set of calculations illustrate this:

```
In [117]: np.ones(2) + np.ones(3)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,) 

In [118]: np.ones(2) + np.ones((1,3))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (1,3) 

In [119]: np.ones(2) + np.ones((3,1))
Out[119]: 
array([[2., 2.],
       [2., 2.],
       [2., 2.]])
In [120]: np.ones((1,2)) + np.ones((3,1))
Out[120]: 
array([[2., 2.],
       [2., 2.],
       [2., 2.]])
```

---

with a missing middle dimension

```
In [126]: np.repeat(A[:,None,:],2,axis=1)+np.ones(4)
Out[126]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]],

       [[ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
        [ 9., 10., 11., 12.]]])
```

There is a more 'advanced' alternative (but not necessarily faster):

```
In [127]: np.broadcast_to(A[:,None,:],(3,2,4))+np.ones(4)
```

Comment: Thanks! For your last comment, how does automatic broadcasting work exactly? Along which dimension would numpy broadcast by default?

Comment: Sorry, just one more question: In some cases, I also have a 1D array `c` of shape `(k,)` which I want to again expand `c` to be `(m, n, k)` and sum it with a 2D array `A` of shape `(m, k)` after expanding to  `(m, n, k)` . Could I do broadcasting in this case? I just tried `c[None, None, :] + A[:, None, :]` but of course that gives me an array of shape `(m,1,k)`...

Comment: I added a `k` example.

Comment: Thanks! Although in my case, the `n` dimension does not appear in the shapes of either `A` or `c`, so I assume that I have to do `np.repeat` on one of them?

Comment: OK, yes if neither has the `n` dimension, then some sort of `repeat` is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You say you want to expand a shape-`(m, n)` array and a shape-`(n, k)` array both to shape `(m, n, k)` and add them together. In that case, you don't need to physically expand your arrays at all; aligning the axes and broadcasting will work fine:

```
A = something of shape (m, n)
B = something of shape (n, k)

C = A[..., np.newaxis] + B
```

This requires no copying of the data in `A` and `B`, and should run much faster than anything involving a physical copy.